# Accessing .NET WebService secured by WS-Security via Java client

Tags: java, .net, web-services, ws-security, rampart

I am trying to access a .NET Web-Service secured via WS-Security from a Java client (AXIS 1.6.2 and Rampart).

Client part:

```
ConfigurationContext ctx = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem("client-repo", null);
AdminServiceStub stub = new AdminServiceStub(null,url);
```

The WSDL (.NET WebService) uses "sp:SecureConversationToken sp:IncludeToken"

```
<sp:SecureConversationToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
```

Invoking the AdminServiceStub generated by wsdl2java fails with a IllegalArgumentException

Generated stub:

```
(__operation).getMessage(org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDLConstants.MESSAGE_LABEL_OUT_VALUE).getPolicySubject().attachPolicy(getPolicy("<wsp:Policy xmlns:wsp=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/..."));
```

This generated code line fails with:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SecurityContextToken doesn't contain any sp:IncludeToken attribute

Does anyone know how to handle this sp:IncludeToken?

Comment: How you generated client code. Eclipse or through command line?

Answer (score 0):

I use wsdl2java.bat shipped with AXIS2 1.6.2

```
wsdl2java.bat -uri http://localhost/AdminService.svc?wsdl  -uw
```